# How can calculate the mode using array. Im only a beginner in programming. its for our finals project

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble getting accurate results on my code to get the mode. it is based on the users input. can anyone help please?
this is the code I'm working on for days

```
    string[] ArrModeInput = new string[20];
    //USER INPUT
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 20 Numbers ");
    //TO INPUT
    for (int stats = 0; stats < ArrModeInput.Length; stats++)
    {
        ArrModeInput[stats] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //CONDITION 
    for (int stats = 0; stats < ArrModeInput.Length; stats++)
    {
        //ArrModeInput[stats] = Console.ReadLine();
        int Count = 0;
        for (int m = 0; m < ArrModeInput.Length; m++)
            if (ArrModeInput[stats] == ArrModeInput[m])
                Count = Count + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("\t\n Mode is " + ArrModeInput[stats] + ". It ocuurs " + Count + " times");
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Please clearly state the issue - what you are expecting to happen, and what is happening instead.

Comment: the formula to find the mode pls

Comment: Google  "formula to find the mode in c#" and you'll find this community already has a lot post on that topic, with accepted answers.